# calling api does not work nextjs getinitialprops

Tags: typescript, axios, next.js

I want to fetch some data from api with next getinitialprops and `axios`

it doesn't work although i added the code here is `getInitialProps`

the file's path is `pages/index.tsx`

```
IndexPage.getInitialProps = async (ctx: any) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "THE_PATH"
    );
    const restaurants = res.data;
    return { restaurants };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};
```

and here is how i tried to use it

```
const IndexPage = (props: any) => {

 <div
      onClick={() => {console.log(props)}}>
```

it doesn't show the props

what am i missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning `{restaurant }`, you need to return the object as the value for `props`;

```
return {
    props: { restaurant }, // will be passed to the page component as props
}
```

> `props` - A required object with the props that will be received by the
> page component.

*Reference*

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Comment: I'm using `getInitalProps` i followed your answer but still is not working, any advice?

Comment: @josephsmith is `res.data` having the correct data?

Comment: yeah res is axios object that contains data status and so on ... could it be next problem with axios or should i configure anything before making request? because when i pass an dummy object to it, it works and also if i make the request separately it works

Comment: or could it be because i'm trying to use getInitialProps inside index.js in pages directory?

Comment: or maybe the api doesn't support server side rendering itself so that request gets failed? because when i make request to jsonplaceholder it works fine

Comment: Your code looks fine. It would be helpful to put a breakpoint before you return the data in `getInitialProps` to make sure you are actually getting the expected data.